# Applescript, Firefox open url in current window

Tags: firefox, applescript

Is there a way to open a url in the current window of Firefox using Applescript?
I figured out how to open a specified url using `open location`:

```
tell application "Firefox" to open location "http://duckduckgo.com"
```

This, however, opens it in a new tab. I searched online and found a work-around that uses System Events to highlight the address bar and enter the url with keystrokes, but it'd be nice to find a more elegant solution (and it makes me chuckle every time I watch the url being ghost-typed in).

I'm running Firefox 3.6.28, which is the newest version that will run on my ppc mac (10.4.11).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System Events is the best you will get for Firefox. You should use either Safari or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In the Applescript Dictionary (found in the File Menu > Open Dictionary > Firefox), you will find a Get URL ability for Firefox. I am running a slightly older version so I am not sure if this would work, but I was able to successfully run:

```
tell application "Firefox"
Get URL "http://duckduckgo.com"
end tell
```

This opened the listed URL in quotes inside the existing Firefox window.

You can see that there are other functions like *OpenURL* which will open the specified URL in  a new window also which are listed in the Firefox Dictionary.